# Can we calculate electric field exactly at surface of charged sphere?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, coulombs-law

For a uniformly charged sphere, electric field at surface of a solid sphere is given as:-
$$E=\frac{KQ}{r²}$$ (if radius is r)

So did we actually calculate electric field at surface of sphere or just outside the sphere using limits?

If not, can we calculate it at surface or is it undefined?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148061/discussion-on-question-by-tolearn-can-we-calculate-electric-field-exactly-at-sur); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

If the charge is really on a sphere (in a thin layer, e.g. charge on a metallic ball), then electric field experienced by the charges themselves is one half of the electric field just above the sphere.

So, electric field just above the charged sphere has magnitude
$$
E(r) = \frac{KQ}{r^2}
$$
and electric field acting on that very charge on the sphere is

$$
E_s(r) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{KQ}{r^2}.
$$

The simplest application of the Gauss law can only supply the first formula, but not the second, because the "pill box" surface coincides with the location of the charges, and the Gauss law formulation does not handle such cases.

But we can find $E_s$ using clever consideration: we express electric field in the neighbourhood (above and below) of a small charged disk on the sphere as sum of two contributions: $\mathbf E_{local}$ due to the small disk of charge, and $\mathbf E_{rest}$ due to rest of the charged sphere (sphere with a hole).

These two fields have to cancel each other inside the sphere just below the small disk, so they have the same magnitude below. Due to symmetry and continuity, they have to have the same magnitude also above the disk. Thus outside the sphere, just above the small disk, we have

$$
E = \frac{KQ}{r^2} = E_{local} + E_{rest} = 2E_{rest}.
$$

Since in electrostatic situation the disk can't act with electric force on itself, net electric field acting on our small charged disk is just due to $E_{rest}$:

$$
E_{rest} = \frac{1}{2}E.
$$
and so this is also the value of electric field $E_s$ we have to assign to points on the sphere.

Comment: The question states: "a uniformly charged sphere," not a thin layer of charge on a metallic ball...

Comment: @hft I understand uniformly charged sphere as thin layer of charge in shape of sphere. If e.g. a uniform 3D charge density inside a sphere is meant, that would be uniformly charged ball.

Comment: In English the word "sphere" can mean either the solid or the surface. The first definition I see on google is "a round solid figure." I guess the question is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: @hft Formulation is a little bit ambiguous, but charge on a sphere is much more common situation than a uniformly charged ball.

Comment: @JánLalinský If the question is about a charged conducting sphere, then this answer may be correct but controversial. You may want to add a reference or two to your answer. e.g. ["What Exactly is the Electric Field at the Surface of a
Charged Conducting Sphere?"](https://tinyurl.com/4x7ah427) or ["Electric field at the surface of a spherical conductor and the recalcitrant factor 1/2"](https://tinyurl.com/38edz4k6) (in Portuguese, but Google Translate can help).

Comment: @DavidBailey I think this is unproblematic part of orthodox EM theory, you can find this as an exercise in Purcell's book in Berkeley physics course.

Comment: @JánLalinský Yes, it is in Purcell, but [Lima](https://tinyurl.com/4x7ah427) claims that Purcell's derivation is incorrect.

Comment: Lima's point is of limited significance - he points out that Purcell's derivation works only for thin charged shell, instead of charged sphere of zero thickness. He is right, but there are other derivations, including his one, which show the result is general and correct even for zero thickness.

Comment: @DavidBailey It's all "angels on the head of a pin": a microscopic model that doesn't hold up when examined microscopically in the laboratory. Real surfaces are *complicated*. This is applied math for mathematics sake, not physics.

Answer (score 2):

> For a uniformly charged sphere, electric field at surface of sphere is given as:-
> $$E=\frac{KQ}{r²}$$ (if radius is r)

Yes. Note: My answer assumes you are asking about a spherical solid of uniform charge density. I.e., by "sphere" I assume you mean the round solid, not just the surface.

> So did we actually calculate electric field at surface of sphere or just outside the sphere using limits?

Yes. If it is a uniformly charged solid sphere, the difference between "just outside... using limits" and "at surface of" does not matter (at least in the limit that "just outside" means it is getting as close to the surface as one would like).

> If not, can we calculate it at surface or is it undefined?

You already did calculate it at the surface. It is not undefined.

Answer (score 2):

A more realistic model of a charged, conductive sphere is that the charge is present in a layer of atomic scale on the surface. The field then assumes a range of values from the vacuum value outside to (approximately) zero in the bulk material.